# I do not receive my variables $_POST with angularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

i am starting to angularJS and i make a program to learn but i don't understand why i don't receive my $_POST variable when i sent

this my controller code

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope,$http, $modalInstance, $modal, Name, Country, City) {

     $scope.Name = Name;
     $scope.City = City;
     $scope.Country = Country;



     $scope.ok = function (Name,Country,City) {

         Country = 'test';

       $http.post('requete.php', Country)
            .success(function (reponse) {
                $scope.PostDataResponse = reponse;
            })
            .error(function (status) {
           alert(status);
                $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data";
            });
      };

     $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
}
```

and this is my requete.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
var_dump($_POST);

echo 1;
?>
```

modal.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header-info">
      <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()"></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Envoyer un SMS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{PostDataResponse}}
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <spam class="spamcenter">Nom : {{Name}}</spam>
        <br>
        <spam class="spamcenter">Pays : {{Country}}</spam>
        <br>
        <spam class="spamcenter">Ville : {{City}}</spam>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok(Name,Country,City)">Envoyer</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

and this is my response variable

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); var_dump($_POST); echo 1; ?>
```

It returns me all the code of my file

i don't understand why and i don't see the trace of my POST in the console network

some one can help me please

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you calling `$scope.ok`

Comment: i edited my post , I have no problem with the function ok() my only problem it's with the http post

Comment: Are you getting any error messege in console ?? And what version of angularjs are you using

Comment: There is multiple things wrong with your code. For now try to change `Country = 'test';` to this `Country = {"country":"some country"};` That will send the data, but you will not get anything usable back from your php script. remove `var_dump($_POST);` and change `echo 1;` to `echo ["success"=>"Received data"];`

Comment: thanks a lot Yolo it s works :D